# How to get the current input ID (CakePHP Formhelper)

Tags: cakephp, formhelper

With CakePHP2's Formhelper I'm trying to create an input, and add the input ID as an data-attr to the wrapping DIV. However I don't know how to get the input ID the way it will be generated. In this case it should be ProductArticleNumber.

My code:

```
function getInputId(){
    $inputId = '';
    return $inputId;
}

echo $this->Form->input('article_number', array('label' => __('Article number'), 'div' => array('data-input-id' => getInputId())));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is what you want to do? `echo $this->Form->input('article_number', 
    array('data-id' => 124,) 
); `

Comment: No, I want to get the CamelCased ModelField that CakePHP sets as the ID of the input.

Comment: Any reason in particular why you want to use the id in a data atrribute and not in, uhm, the id?

Comment: @Eagle If I set the ID of the inner input on the wrapping div I'm having a duplicate ID. What I want is the following: <div data-input-id="X"><input id="X"></div>.

Comment: Oh, didn't see that it was for the div. Anyways, do you want to manipulate the div with js? If so and if you use jQuery, you can use something like `$('#id').parent()`